# Velocity reading from equation

Tags: derivatives, projectile-motion

So I have this question which I am struggling to solve. As far as I can tell I believe it might have something to do with taking the derivative of the equation so that you can find an expression for velocity but I am really unsure of how to go about doing this question, however, and any help on it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

The motion of a pendulum subject to damping is described by:
x = Ae^(-0.1t) * cos(4t + (PI/2))

If x = 5 at t = 0, find the velocity of the pendulum when it first passes through its central position

Comment: Use the information given to find A. Differentiate x using the product rule to get a formula for v. What is the period of x and when does it first reach its central position? Substitute that value of t into v.

Comment: Worked perfectly thanks very much!

Comment: Your expression gives x=0 at t=0.